Mixed model estimates
The dataset obk.long has 3 levels for treatment, why when running a mixed model with afex is it returning estimates for only treatment 1 and treatment 2 and not treatment 3?
m2 <- mixed(value ~ treatment + (1|id), obk.long)
coef(summary(m2))

              Estimate Std. Error df   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  5.4833333  0.3751349 13 14.616965 1.898692e-09
treatment1  -1.2833333  0.5321164 13 -2.411753 3.138653e-02
treatment2   0.7666667  0.5645824 13  1.357936 1.975866e-01
```


This question is similar to: Missing Coefficients in Linear Regression with Multiple Categorical Variables in R. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. In the standard R coding of categorical predictors, the intercept is the outcome estimate at the reference level and the other coefficients are differences of other levels from that.

There's nothing special about the afex package or mixed models in this regard; that package is more or less a convenient wrapper for many standard R functions. If you use the default R treatment contrasts and only have a single 3-level categorical predictor as a fixed effect, then the intercept is the model estimate for the reference level of the predictor (evidently treatment 3 in your data).
